# Possible to combine `SVNListParentPath` and `SVNMasterURI`?

Tags: svn, mod-dav-svn

I have been trying to set up Apache to access subversion repositories such that:

- Makes use of repository collections, i.e. `SVNParentPath` points to a folder containing repositories.
- Uses `SVNMasterURI` to transparently proxy commits to a master server.

My initial attempt was like this:

```
<Location "/collection">
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /path/to/collection
    SVNMasterURI http://master/collection
    SVNListParentPath on
    AuthzForceUsernameCase Lower
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /path/to/access-file
</Location>
```

With this configuration, the transparent proxy commits work as intended. However, when I try to browse to `http://svn-server/collection/` i get `403 Forbidden` and the error log contains `The URI does not contain the name of a repository.`.

[Trailing slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642583/svn-trailing-slash-in-location-directive-works-on-browser-but-gives-403-error-i) seems to have great importance here, so after trying out all combinations of trailing slash on `Location`, `SVNParentPath` and `SVNMasterURI` I have found that:

- For `SVNListParentPath` to work, `Location` must have a trailing slash.
- For `SVNMasterURI` to work, `Location` must *not* have a trailing slash.

All of this is on Ubuntu 12.04, Apache 2.2.22, mod_dav_svn 1.6.17dfsg-3ubuntu3.

*My question is:*

Is there a way to use `SVNListParentPath` and `SVNMasterURI` at the same time?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I have the same use case and would be very interested in a solution/workaround.

Comment: I'm afraid not, my workaround was to add a simple script that does the repository list rendering when browsing to `http://svn-server/collection/`.

Answer (score 2):

If that's an option for you, upgrade Subversion, and mod_dav_svn, to version 1.8.10, or later. The "trailing slash bug" has been fixed in the meantime, and SVNListParentPath works fine with `<location /collection>`.

I can confirm, that SVNMasterURI is very sensitive to `<location>`. Make sure that the path is the same in master, and slaves repositories.